# Android - How to pass a Bitmap in a constractor?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, android-bitmap

**EDITED**

I have this class:

```
    public class Item {

        private Bitmap image;

        public Item(Bitmap image) {
            this.image = image;
        }
```

I have also the main activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //the question is about this line
        Item item = new Item(???);

    }
}
```

How to call the constructor of the Item From MainActivity (inside onCreate)? I do not know how to refer to a Bitmap from Resources.

The image I want to pass to the constructor is located in:
**app >> res >> mipmap >> cat.png**

Comment: pls ask question clearly.. You need bitmap from drawable ahh?

Comment: @RanjithKumar I added the link to the image I want to refer to

Comment: More context is required. Please add to the question

Comment: @IvanWooll I have edited the question, Now it's well explained

Comment: @RanjithKumar Can u see the updated question?

Comment: If answer working put tick mark of the answer.. else ask me again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() , R.drawable.cat);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you can convert bitmap to drawable

```
Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cat);
Bitmap bitmap= ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();
```

Answer (score 0):

in java , you can call constructor By building an instance of your class .

in your Question :

```
new Item(bitmap);
```

you can refer to resource bitmap in your Activity by doing this :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources() , R.drawable.cat);
```

and in Fragment :

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getAvtivity().getResources() , R.drawable.cat);
```